# Find the color of a pixel at a point within a VGroup

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm having trouble with this code can anybody help...

```
var imageMap:ImageSnapshot= ImageSnapshot.captureImage(object);
var pixelValue:uint = imageMap.bitmapData.getPixel(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/sv_SE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/ImageSnapshot.html), there is no `bitmapData` property of the ImageSnap class.  Instead you can use the static `ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData` function to get a BitmapData snapshot of your object.

```
var imageMap:BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(object);
var pixelValue:uint = imageMap.getPixel(x,y);
```